# Can I set up my own DNS server on a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows-10, dns

I have my Windows 10 PC, Hyper-V on which sits the Ubuntu Server where I host my web site on Apache HTTP server. Now it all works locally but let's say I buy a domain name and make my web site public. I want to learn to admininster my own DNS server, create DNS records etc. Is it possible to create a DNS Server on the Windows 10 machine and if it is then how can I do that?

Comment: This is likely possible (all you need is an authorative DNS server) but there is a gotcha - in order to correctly handle DNS you should have a minimum of 2 servers [ some people fake it with 2 IP addresses pointing to the same server, works, but not a great idea).  I'm a Linux person, so I can't give specific advice, but Google came up with https://maradns.samiam.org/ which - at least on the packet - claims to do what you need with respect of being an authorative DNS server you can run under Windows.

Comment: @davidgo 
1. `in order to correctly handle DNS you should have a minimum of 2 servers` - but I have only one Ubuntu Server machine and one HTTP server which is Apache. What is meant by the second server here?
2. And what if I set up a DNS Server on the Ubuntu Server where my web site is hosted?

Comment: The second server would hold a copy of the same DNS data as the first one. (Usually you set it up so that it automatically replicates the data using AXFR from the primary.) It's not so much about "correctly" handling DNS, but about achieving reliability/uptime, as everything on the domain and all subdomains would become inaccessible if the single DNS server went unavailable (e.g. if it suddenly decided to spend a few hours applying Windows Updates).

Comment: @user1686 What is AXFR?

Comment: AXFR is zone transfer; the built-in replication mechanism in DNS. (While normal DNS requests give results for a single name/single type, an "AXFR" request returns results for _all_ names in the domain, including subdomains and all data types.) Try running `nslookup` on Windows, entering `server ns4.gnu.org`, then `ls -d gnu.org` and the 'ls' subcommand will do an AXFR query. Alternatively `dig gnu.org axfr @ns4.gnu.org`.

Comment: @user1686 This is way too complicated for me now. I'll have to do some research before I can understand this. But, thank you anyway.

Comment: You can definately set up nameservers in Ubuntu - (I do this).  but, practically speaking you are supposed - and should - have at least 2 machines and 2 world reachable static IP's - and a way to ensure the DNS information on both is the same.  (You dont need to worry about AXFR records if you can do this another way - AXFR is just 1 way if doing this - for domains that dont change much you can mirror the configuration - but I find it easier to just use a dns server that uses an sql backend and I replicate that)

Comment: Common nameservers used under Linux include BIND and DNSMasq, but I would recommend PowerDNS with a replicated mysql  backend and a web interface if you are just starting out)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, DNS is just a (relatively) simple TCP&UDP-based service – but there are really few DNS servers that are made to run on Windows; it's simply not a popular platform for DNS hosting, outside from MS Active Directory environments.

- The previously mentioned [MaraDNS](https://maradns.samiam.org/) runs on Windows.
- Microsoft DNS Server – but it's only available in Windows Server (which you could run via Hyper-V, as Microsoft provides a free 180-day [trial](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2022)), not in the "consumer" versions of Windows.
- …That's about it? (ISC BIND 9 *used to be* available for Windows, but no longer is. They now suggest running the Linux version through WSL instead.)

As you already have a Linux VM on Hyper-V, you should run the DNS server on that instead. (A few common DNS servers for Linux are BIND 9, PowerDNS, Knot, NSD.)

Note that you're specifically looking for software made to work as an **authoritative** DNS server. There are also some DNS servers which are meant to run as resolvers (aka caches/proxies) and can't actually host a domain; e.g. dnsmasq or Unbound are not really suitable.

Comment: Technitium DNS Server can be authoritative, is cross platform, and has a bunch of other features.